# How to live read text file into textbox in C#

Tags: c#

How to read live text from a text file into textbox in C#? The file is being updated all the time by another process, and we need to keep displaying the updated text in the textbox.

Any hint will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably think about using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to track changes to the file, and refresh the contents of the textbox whenever you detect a change.  You'll need to be careful about concurrency and file locking, though.  Probably the safest way to do it would be to read the file into a separate string object, and only update the textbox once you are happy that the read operation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystemWatcher` class might help you doing this:

[FileSystemWatcher Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and catch the event Onchanged. And handle it by reading the file again!